# max number across rows in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, max, rows

I have a dataframe in pandas and I am trying to find the easiest way to find the max value across rows and create a new column with the max value.  See Below as example

```
MA10D     MA30D      MA50D       MA100D      MA200D     
19.838  17.197333   16.5896     16.5207     16.52065        
19.296  17.015333   16.4758     16.4676     16.48300 
18.722  16.833000   16.3680     16.4106     16.44475
```

So in the first row of the new column I would want to return a 19.838 then 19.296 and 18.722 (it is just by chance that in this example all numbers are under MA10D column).  Can someone help me find the best way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried `df.max(axis = 1)`?

Comment: Why was this considered too broad?  There is one obvious solution that is simple, clean, and pandastic, and it happens to be the one that was given twice before the question was closed.  Have the people who closed the question ever used pandas before?

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas, the vast majority of operations apply *through rows*, i.e. per column, and it is called `axis=0`. When it makes sense to apply these operations *through columns*, i.e. per row, use `axis=1`.

Finding the maximum is an expected operation on a dataframe. `df.max()` is equivalent to `df.max(axis=0)` and gives one resulting row with the max per column. For your case, use `df.max(axis=1)`.